# IOT , Raspberry pi, Windows IOT

Tags: windows, arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, windowsiot

I want to upload Arduino sketch via Raspberry pi using windows 10 IOT platform (Visual studio universal application), Has anybody any idea how to do this?

Sketch from cloud > > > > Raspberry pi ------> Arduino

In this diagram sketch download from the cloud and via Rpi upload to Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straight forward as the question stated the flow.

```
Cloud --> RPi --> Arduino.
```

## Step 1

Upload the sketch in the Cloud Instance (ftp or http)

## Step 2

In the windows IoT Core, wget the sketch file and Install Arduino IDE

```
wget http://cloud-server/sketches/program1.ino
```

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

## Step 3

Reboot the RPi

```
sudo reboot
```

## Step 4

When the RPi rebooted, 
open the Arduino IDE and select the port to upload the sketch

```
/dev/tty/USB0
```

If the Step 2 wont go successful then try to install windows gnu tool chain
http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/

to compile and install piduino as follows

```
mkdir hardware/RaspberryPi
cd hardware/RaspberryPi
git clone https://github.com/me-no-dev/RasPiArduino piduino
```

Answer (score -1):

It could have been use full if you have mentioned the whole problem you have. I will try to answer the best I can:

**Solution One:**
You can maintain a shared memory for the Raspberry pi and Arduino board. (It can be some external SD card). Get the code from the cloud using Raspberry pi and write this using file streams into the shared memory. Then read this file from the same shared memory using Arduino.

**Solution Two:**
If you are not worried about the exact file and your only concern in the logic, interface the Arduino to Raspberry pi as a slave device. Use the Arduino I/O ports to read the digital signals or values from raspberry pi which are generated according to the code you got from cloud using windows10 IOT platform.

I hope this could help you to some extent.